# How to construct a security regression Test?

Tags: automated-tests, zap, regression-testing

**Details:**

I had already read several articles regarding a security-specific regression test, which could not be more different. Some advocate a strict mixture of CI pipelines and manual pentest procedures, others swear by no CI automated test procedures and manual test procedures.

I myself would prefer a clear mixture of several procedures for the security regression test. Here just about a connection of Owasp Zap + Docker and Jenkins as a pipeline integration.

**The questions:**

- What are your experiences regarding security regression?
- How do you handle the corresponding workflow in the Agile area and in the definition of Ready and Done?
- Do you do more manual security regression or do you swear by corresponding CI tooling and automation?
  Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

We actually have a Google Summer of Code project for retesting vulnerabilities found by ZAP scans.

The blog https://pranavsaxena17.github.io/GSoC-with-ZAP/ is a bit light but hopefully the student will update it soon. In any case the project is progressing well.